# Linker not showing the customized library path

Tags: linker

The problem is I have Aspell.so and it is using system libs - but I need to over-ride using $LD_LIBRARY_PATH , but changing this variable helped in one system but not another !
oes $LD_LIBRARY_PATH decide the ldd directory or is there anything that overrides it ?
I set it to me local directory , but still ldd is taking the libraries from the syste /usr/lib directory .

Its like my local machine  is a 32bit . I compile it here and port it to a test server which is 64 bit Centos4.8 ( works fine ) .... and also copy to production which is 64bit ( doesnt work fine ) Redhat 4.8

I do export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/mydir ...and just try ldd aspell.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The path specifies not just where to search, but when to search, so you should put /mydir at the start if you want it to take priority over other entires.

If you want to force it to use your aspell.so instead you can use `LD_PRELOAD=/mydir/aspell.so` instead.